# Make valgrind to collect the data on request

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, massif

I have got a memory leak which I'm trying to track with massif.
The problem is that the leak happens always like couple of hours after an app is started.
Now application that runs on massif is about 20 times slower than normal, thus for the leak to happen I must wait like 100 hours or more.
I was even trying to wait this time, but it happened that no leak was there. I suspect that the leaks may somehow occur only when my project is running on full speed?
Since it is not possible to attach valgrind to running process, is there maybe the way to postpone valgrind so it will collect the data after some time, or even better on the request? This way I could wait some time when the program is running fine (with hopefully normal speed), and start logging at the moment leaks are occurring.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For memory leaks, `memcheck` is the best tool that is part of Valgrind. It is possible to trigger leak checks with memcheck. You can either modify your executable to add Valgrind client requests, or else run under the gdb/vgdb and use the monitor command.

The only thing that I'm aware of for Massif is a [recent patch](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=424149) to allow client requests. You would have to download the Valgrind source, apply this patch and build Valgrind. I have no experience with it.

You might also consider `heapcheck` and if modifying your build is possible, leak sanitizer.

Comment: memcheck I was trying, but this tool seems to be even more resource-hungry than massif. Second thing is that it seems that the leaks I'm experiencing are being freed when application is closed. Third memcheck output file is over 30MB. I was trying to analyze that and I just gave up. In my particular case massif seems to be just enough to find the problem. I will check the other suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Don't give up. Usually a huge error log does not mean a huge number of different errors. Often there are a relatively small number of errors that occur a huge number of times. Start with the first errors and keep fixing them.

Comment: This is another problem, since I'm only responsible of a small part of a whole application (I'm developing single .so lib) I cant fix other bugs where there are like tons of them.
However just as I commented in my answer, I found libleak that did the job.

Answer (score 0):

For those who also stucked with similar issue as me.
I found other solution. Instead using of valgring I did used libleak tool which does pretty much the same job as massif, but it's way less resource consuming.
For details, please refer to:
https://github.com/WuBingzheng/libleak